# how to reset the pointer in BST?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a Binary search tree with functionalities such as Deleting a node, finding the minimum node, maximum node, etc. But I am not able to Delete a node nor find Maximum or Minimum value in the tree. My take is that when I am inserting the nodes, the pointer to the node references to the last node hence my program cannot iterate from the root node. Any suggestion?

```
 #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;

    struct BstNode
    {
        BstNode* left;
    BstNode* right;
    int data;   
};

BstNode* GetnewNode(int data)
{
    BstNode* newNode=new BstNode();
    
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    
    return newNode;
     
} 

BstNode* Insert(BstNode* root ,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=GetnewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data<=root->data)
    {
        root=Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        root=Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    
    return root;
}   

bool Search(BstNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(data==root->data)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(data<=root->data)
    {
        return Search(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        return Search(root->right,data);
    }
}

int FindMin(BstNode* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(root->left!=NULL)
        {
            root=root->left;
        }
    }
    
    return root->data;
    
    
}
bool IsBstUtil(BstNode* root, int minvalue, int maxvalue)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    return true;
    
    if(root->data<minvalue && root->data >maxvalue && IsBstUtil(root->left,minvalue,root->data) && IsBstUtil(root->right,root->data,maxvalue))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool IsBinarySearchTree(BstNode* root)
{
    return IsBstUtil(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
}

int FindMax(BstNode* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
        
    }
    else
    {
        while(root->right!=NULL)
        {
            root=root->right;
        }
    }
    
    return root->data;
}
BstNode* del(BstNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return root;
    else if(data<=root->data)
        root->left=del(root->left,data);
    else if(data>root->data)
        root->right=del(root->right,data);
    
    else
    {
        if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        {   
            root=NULL;
            delete root;
        }
        else if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            BstNode* temp=root;
            root=root->right;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
        else if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            BstNode* temp=root;
            root=root->left;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    BstNode* root=NULL;
    root=Insert(root,1);
    root=Insert(root,3);
    root=Insert(root,4);
    
}
```

Comment: The obvious solution would be to not overwrite the `root` variable you have in `main` with a pointer to a non-root element

Comment: @SaiSreenivas can you provide me with a solution? I am a beginner at BST right now

Comment: @UnholySheep basically what you are suggesting this that I should assign the root variable in the main function only for the first time I am calling the Insert method for the root Node? And not for the other Insert calls?

Answer (score 0):

Just instead of doing `root = Insert(root->left,data);` you should do set it as left to the root i.e
`root->left = Insert(root->left,data);`

**Insert function:**

```cpp
BstNode* Insert(BstNode* root ,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=GetnewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data<=root->data)
    {
        // setting the left to root 
        root->left=Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        // setting the right to root 
        root->right=Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    
    // returning the root itself
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally worked. I didn't know I was making such a silly mistake